# How to activate a state and pass object to the new view?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

app.js:

```
 $stateProvider.state('datasource', {
            url: '/datasource',
            templateUrl: 'views/datasource.html',
            controller: 'datasourceController'
        });

        $stateProvider.state('datasourceList', {
            url: '/datasource/:datasourceId',
            templateUrl: 'views/datasource.list.html',
            controller: 'datasourceController'
        });
```

Then, I've a function activated onClick defined in (datasourceController)

```
$scope.submitSelected = function() {
    if (angular.isDefined($scope.selectedSource)) {
        $scope.datasource = dataSourcesService.find($scope.selectedSource.id);
        $state.go('datasourceList', {datasourceId : datasource});
    }
 }
```

As I said, in my `datasource.html` view have an element click that triggers `submitSelected()` function

I can retrieve data successfully from my service based on ID when call it in function.

Problem is, i cant access the results (scope) of it in the view `datasource.list.html` after changing the state.

Comment: Can you please add code of datasource.list.html and datasourceController

Comment: `datasourceController` only has that function that i've already add. `datasource.list.html`has `{{datasource}}`

Comment: From where do we get selectedSource and selectedSource.id?

Comment: `<div class="row" ng-repeat="datasource in datasources"  ng-click="setSelected(datasource)">`

Comment: Frankly, speaking your incomplete code is blocking the solution. Can you please add complete controller and views

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add 'param' in state config

```
$stateProvider.state('datasource', {
        url: '/datasource',
        templateUrl: 'views/datasource.html',
        controller: 'datasourceController'
    });

    $stateProvider.state('datasourceList', {
        url: '/datasource/:datasourceId',
        templateUrl: 'views/datasource.list.html',
         params:      ['index', 'anotherKey'],
        controller: 'datasourceController'
    });
```

And get values using $stateParams in another controller

```
 app.controller('datasourceController', function($scope, $stateParams) {
var index = $stateParams.index;
var anotherKey = $stateParams.anotherKey;
```

});